# Looking for font used in a scanned image (similar to palatino)

Tags: fonts

Does anybody know what the font in the picture of link is called?

(of course, that I can add it in LaTeX)

[image: https://goo.gl/ftG69]

I think it  looks like *palatino* font, but the letter 's' is not as wide as the image.

Comment: IT is not listed the [Latex Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) So maybe you need to find a OpenFont / TrueType solution with `xetex`